# Problema relación Uno a muchos Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo dos tablas:

- **Módulo:** id, modulo
- **Permiso:** id, permiso, idModulo

La relación en el modelo del Módulo:

```
 public function permisos() {
    return $this->hasMany('Moltareas\Permiso\PermisoModel');
}
```

La relación en el modelo Permiso:

```
  public function modulo() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Moltareas\Modulo\ModuloModel', 'idModulo');
}
```

Al imprimir:

```
   $modulos = $this->moduloRepo->search();
   dd($modulos->permisos->permiso);
```

Me arroja este error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$permisos
```

Comment: $this->moduloRepo->search() genera una colección, ¿verdad?

Comment: Es lo mismo que hacer User::All(); ... solo que uso el patron repositorio...

Comment: ¿Entonces no deberias de especificar uno de los módulos que acabas de obtener? Es decir, al final User:All() genera una colección. ¿Ya intentaste con $modulos[0]->permisos?

Comment: Si, lo he solucionado con un foreach y concatenando de la forma que decís. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No sé si el staff de stackoverflow lo aprobará, soy nuevo por aquí. Pero incluiré la respuesta por si alguien viene por acá para que se beneficie de esto.

Answer (score 1):

```
$modulos = $this->moduloRepo->search();
```

La instrucción de arriba genera una colección. Por lo tanto necesitas especificar el elemento del cual deseas obtener los permisos.

Cambia

```
dd($modulos->permisos->permiso);
```

Por esto (especificando un elemento)

```
dd($modulos[0]->permisos->permiso);
```

Answer (score 0):

Le estas dando una dirección diferente le estas diciendo "Moltareas\Permiso\PermisoModel" Cuando en la documentación te dice "return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');"

Tu le estas dando la dirección con el nombre de tu app, luego el nombre de una carpeta, luego el nombre del Modelo...

Las direcciones a la hora de hacer la relación en tu caso sería "Moltareas\NombredelModelo".

A menos que tengas los modelos en carpetas diferentes.

Comment: Eso la manejo con PSR-4 para que acepte esa dirección.